# Spark ML ALS recommendation algorithm returning already watched items

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Spark ML implementation of Alternate Least Squares algorithm for recommendations, produces a model than can be applied to already watched items (**training.itemCol**, for watched movies, in the example below), in order to suggest new items (**movieRecs** in the example). How is it possible that the method returns already watched (non-new) items as part of the results (**userRecs**)?

```
als = ALS(maxIter=5, regParam=0.01, userCol="userId", itemCol="movieId", ratingCol="rating",
          coldStartStrategy="drop")

model = als.fit(training)

userRecs = model.recommendForAllUsers(10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `recommendForAllUsers()` does is

- Take the user blocks and item blocks (along with their vector embeddings) learnt at the time of training.
- Compute the cross join of user and item blocks.
- Calculate dot product of the embeddings.
- Select top `n` products based on the value of dot product, for each user.

In the above process, the cross join broadens the user-item space. Since the model was trained with those items (watched movies), the dot product for them will always be significant. Hence, the items appearing for a user at the training time appears at the time of recommendation for the same user.